# Energy of a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator $(x-a)$ vs $x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to compare the energy of quantum harmonic oscillators at different positions. Intuitively, I think they should be identical since the only difference is $(x)$ versus $(x-a)$.

$(m=1, \hbar =1)$

My Hamiltonian is:
$$\hat{H} = \left((-i\hbar)^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right) + \frac{\omega^2 x^2}{2} $$

Here are my ground state wave functions:
$$\psi_1 = \frac{\omega _1^{5/4} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \omega _1}}{2 \sqrt[4]{\pi }}$$

$$\psi_2 = \frac{\omega _2^{5/4} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x-a)^2 \omega _2}}{2 \sqrt[4]{\pi }}$$

Everything works out with $\psi_1$, it is normalized and the energy is $\frac{\omega_1 \hbar}{2}$. For $\psi_2$: it is still normalized, $<\psi_2|\hat{x}|\psi_2> = a$, but the energy is $\frac{\omega_2 \hbar}{2} + \frac{\omega_2^2a^2}{2}$. In the limit as $a \rightarrow 0$ it is correct but should there be the $\frac{\omega_2^2a^2}{2}$ term? Maybe it is fine because it is a constant shift?

Comment: @SolubleFish Please don't answer in a comment.  Note you can get more reputation points from an answer than a comment, so it's to your advantage to post an answer.  Answers do not have to be long, just clear.

Answer (score 4):

The HO centered around $x=a$ has Hamiltonian $H_2 = p^2/2m + \omega^2 (x-a)^2/2$. You should be able to check that $\langle \psi_2|H_2|\psi_2\rangle  = \hbar \omega/2$.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have inconsistencies in your setup. You say that $\hbar = 1 $ but you have it in your Hamiltonian. Also, there is a factor of 2 missing in the Hamiltonian. With the factor of 2 mistake you should not have gotten correct energies, even for $\psi_1$.

Also, $\psi_2$ is not an energy eigenfunction of your (or the corrected) Hamiltonian. You will find that
$$\hat{H} \psi_2 = f(x)\psi_2$$
so it's not an eigenfunction.

If you want to shift the center of the harmonic oscillator, you can't simply change the $x\to x-a$ in the solution. You must also change it in the Hamiltonian potential.